# Typescript static function isn't receiving arguments

Tags: angular, typescript, vue.js, oop, static

I'm trying to reach a static function from within a Typescript object's public function, but it doesn't seem to work.

The goal is to implement an Angular-style form validator in Vue. The parent component defines an array of `ReactiveFormElement` objects, which are controllers for the actual form controls. These can receive two parameters upon creation: a value and an array of validators.

The validators are static functions in another object.

Here's a simplified rundown:

Parent component:

```
import ReactiveFormElement from '@/components/ReactiveFormElement';
import Validators from '@/services/validators';
...

    public formData = {
        title: new ReactiveFormElement('', [Validators.required]),
    };
```

The reactive form element:

```
export default class ReactiveFormElement {

    constructor(
        public value?: any,
        public validators: Function[] = []) { }

    public validate() {
        console.log('Sending to validator: ' + this.value);
        const error = validator.call(this.value);
    }
}
```

And the validators look like this:

```
export default class Validators {

    static required(value: any) {
        console.log('Validator received: ', value);
        if (typeof value === 'undefined' || !value)
            return 'This value is required'
        else
            return null;
    }
}
```

**The problem:** Whatever I pass to the validator will end up being `undefined`. As you see, I'm printing the value I'm sending from `ReactiveFormElement.validate()` to `Validators.require()` to the console. The output is:

```
Sending to validator: Some string
Validator received: undefined
```

Why is it undefined?

It doesn't help if the validator function isn't static.
It doesn't help if I use `apply` instead of `call` (putting the value into an array, of course).
Interestingly the validator works if I call it from the parent component. But it refuses to work from inside `ReactiveFormElement`.

Comment: Why are you using `.call`?

Comment: Literally because why not?

Comment: That's a joke right? It's the reason your code didn't work and you weren't doing anything that required it.

Comment: Why wouldn't it? There's nothing wrong with call(), it works just fine now. See the two answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your scoping. If you pass `this` as a first argument to the call method (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) your method will receive the correct input.

Working snippet:

```
class ReactiveFormElement {

    constructor(
        public value?: any,
        public validators: Function[] = []) { }

    public validate() {
        console.log('Sending to validator: ' + this.value);
        this.validators.forEach(validator =>
            validator.call(this, this.value));
    }
}

class Validators {

    static required(value: any) {
        console.log('Validator received: ', value);
        if (typeof value === 'undefined' || !value)
            return 'This value is required'
        else
            return null;
    }
}

const formElement = new ReactiveFormElement('foo', [Validators.required]);
formElement.validate();
```